# foreach loop

Tags: c#, validation

I have two questions

1) my interface i have interface called IRegister and within it i have another interface called IPerson, is that right practice?

2) i have two List(IRegister, IPerson) both can have one or more rows.

what is the best way to loop both List? within GetValidationRules?

```
public interface IRegister 
{
    string FirstName { get; }
    string MiddleName { get; }
    string LastName { get; }
    string EmailAddress { get; }        
    List<IPerson> Student { get; }
}


public static List<ValidationRule> GetValidationRules(List<IRegister> register)
    {
        List<ValidationRule> validationRules = new List<ValidationRule>();  



        foreach (IRegister myregister in register)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myregister.FirstName))
                validationRules.Add(new ValidationRule("Reg", "Must have aFirst Name"));
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myregister.LastName))
                validationRules.Add(new ValidationRule("Reg", "Must have a Last Name"));
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myregister.EmailAddress))
                validationRules.Add(new ValidationRule("Reg", "Must have a Email Address"));

  IPerson here? how
        }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are talking about C#, but it would be nice if you specified that.

Comment: plz rephrase your question. i dont think many ppl will get this

Comment: In an effort to understand - You have a Registration and, if the registration is valid, you want to create a Person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish based on your question... I am guessing that you're wondering how to iterate through the `Student` propery of IRegister inside the loop...

```
public interface IRegister 
{
    string FirstName { get; }
    string MiddleName { get; }
    string LastName { get; }
    string EmailAddress { get; }        
    List<IPerson> Student { get; }
}

public static List<ValidationRule> GetValidationRules(List<IRegister> register)
{
    List<ValidationRule> validationRules = new List<ValidationRule>();  



    foreach (IRegister myregister in register)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myregister.FirstName))
            validationRules.Add(new ValidationRule("Reg", "Must have aFirst Name"));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myregister.LastName))
            validationRules.Add(new ValidationRule("Reg", "Must have a Last Name"));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myregister.EmailAddress))
            validationRules.Add(new ValidationRule("Reg", "Must have a Email Address"));

        foreach (IPerson person in myregister.Student) 
        {
            // Not sure what properties you want to check for because 
            // you didn't show us what the IStudent interface looks like
            // so I will just assume that the IStudent object has a  
            // property for EmailAddress as well

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(person.EmailAddress))
                validationRules.Add(new ValidationRule("Reg", "Student must have a Email Address"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Um, nested loop at your marker.

`foreach (IPerson peep in myregister.Student)
    {
        ...
    }`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to loop over all of the `IPerson` instances is to use SelectMany to flatten the list of `IPerson` within the `IRegister` instances.  For example

```
foreach ( var person in register.SelectMany(x => x.Student))  {
  ...
}
```

This has the effect of creating an `IEnumerable<IPerson>` which contains all `IPerson` instances from all of the `IRegister` values.